# How do I sum a key and group by value using Ramda?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have data like this:

```
const items = [
  {category: 'food', amount: 5},
  {category: 'food', amount: 5},
  {category: 'transport', amount: 2},
  {category: 'travel', amount: 11},
  {category: 'travel', amount: 1},
]
```

How can I sum `amount` and group by each `category` yielding:

```
{
  food : 10,
  transport : 2,
  travel : 12,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduceBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#reduceBy):

```
R.reduceBy((acc, next) => acc + next.amount, 0, R.prop('category'))(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduceBy` is probably a good idea. Here's an alternative in case you find it useful.

Start with an `itemize` function:

```js
const itemize = ({category: c, amount: a}) => ({[c]: a});

itemize({category: 'food', amount: 5});
//=> {food: 5}
```

Then define a function that can either add or merge items:

```js
const additem = mergeWith(add);

additem({food: 5}, {food: 5});
//=> {food: 10}

additem({food: 5}, {transport: 2});
//=> {food: 5, transport: 2}
```

Finally use these two functions in a reducer:

```js
reduce((a, b) => additem(a, itemize(b)), {}, items);
```